# How to display department (once) and list of all employees working in that department?

Tags: sql, oracle

For the schema `epartments(department_id, department_name) employees(last_name, department_id, salary)`
I want to display the `department_id, department_name, count(employees),avg(salary),last_name,salary`
I have tried using the following query

```
SELECT d1.department_id,d1.department_name,d1."count",d1."avg",e.last_name,e.salary
FROM   employees e
INNER JOIN (SELECT d.department_id,d.department_name,count(e.last_name) AS "count",round(avg(e.salary),2) AS "avg"
                FROM employees e,departments d
                WHERE e.department_id=d.department_id
                GROUP BY d.department_id,d.department_name) d1
    ON e.department_id=d1.department_id;
```

While it displays the correct output it is not in the format I want.
The above query gives output as

```
90  Executive   3   19333.33    King    24000
90  Executive   3   19333.33    Kochhar 17000
90  Executive   3   19333.33    De Haan 17000
60  IT          3   6400        Hunold  9000
60  IT          3   6400        Ernst   6000
60  IT          3   6400        Lorentz 4200
50  Shipping    5   3500        Mourgos 5800
```

While it should be like

```
90  Executive   3   19333.33    King    24000
                                Kochhar 17000
                                De Haan 17000
60  IT          3   6400        Hunold  9000
                                Ernst   6000
                                Lorentz 4200
50  Shipping    5   3500        Mourgos 5800
```

Comment: Instead of doing this in SQL, do this formatting in presentation layer code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to show something like `''` instead of those data in your query, I think you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` for that like this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d1.department_id
                             ORDER BY d1.department_id)) = 1 THEN
        d1.department_id
    ELSE
        Null
END
```

for columns: `d1.department_id`,`d1.department_name`,`d1."count"`,`d1."avg"`.